# Spectrum of Hardy operators on $L^p[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $Hf(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ denote the well-known (continuous) Hardy (someone called Cesáro) operators. For $1<p<+\infty$, it can shown that $H$ is bounded on $L^p[0,+\infty)$ with operator norm $\frac{p}{p-1}$. It is also true that $H$ is bounded on $L^p[0,1]$ with the same norm. For the spectrum, when $p=2$, [Brown, Halmos and Shields (1965) proved](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for%3A%20Title%3D%28cesaro%20operator%29&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&fmt=doc&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=cesaro%20operator&s6=&s7=&s8=All&searchin=&sort=citations&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=187085) that $H$ are both respectively unitary equivalent to certain shift operators and hence deduce that $$\sigma(H,L^2[0,\infty))=\{\lambda: |\lambda-1|=1\}$$ and $$\sigma(H,L^2[0,1])=\{\lambda:|\lambda-1|\leq 1\}.$$
Tow years later, [Boyd proved](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/14174/1/math_029_fasc_001_002_031-034.pdf) that $\sigma(H,L^p[0,+\infty)=\{\lambda: |\lambda-\frac{p}{2(p-1)}|=\frac{p}{2(p-1)}\}$. **It is reasonable to guess** $$\sigma(H,L^p[0,1])=\{\lambda: |\lambda-\frac{p}{2(p-1)}|\leq\frac{p}{2(p-1)}\}.$$

But I have not find references up to now. Is anyone know some references about this? Of course one can show the spectrum of $H$ on $L^p[0,1]$ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above question is positively answered by [this paper](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/14426/1/math_035_027-029.pdf).